# Managing the back button with nested fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `MainActivity` with a `content_container` to load `Fragments` in it.

In one of the `Fragment` I also have a `sub_container` to load `Fragments`.

In the `MainActivity` i manage the back button with a stack of `Fragment`:

```
public Fragment addFragmentToStack(Fragment fragment){
    if(fragmentStack.size()>MAX_NUM_FRAGMENTS){
        fragmentStack.remove(0);
    }
    return fragmentStack.push(fragment);
}   

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (fragmentStack.size() > 0) {
        fragmentStack.pop();
        if (MyApplication.fragmentStack.size() > 0) {               
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_container, fragmentStack.peek());
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

and whenever I want to replace a `Fragment` in my `content_container` I use

```
Fragment someFragment = new SomeFragment(); 
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_container, ((MainActivity)getActivity()).addFragmentToStack(someFragment), "");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

One `Fragment` is a gallery, with a menu to load a `photos` or a `videos` `Fragment` in it (so the gallery is the parent `Fragment` and the photos and videos `Fragments` are children).

In order to be able to add the photo gallery and the video gallery in the stack, I use in the GalleryFragment:

```
if(mType.equals("photos")){
    Fragment videoFragment = new VideoFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.sub_container, videoFragment, "");
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).addFragmentToStack(this);
}
else{
    Fragment photoFragment = new PhotoFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.sub_container, photoFragment, "");
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).addFragmentToStack(this);
}
```

i.e. I add the parent `GalleryFragment` in the stack.

When I go from the videos to the photos gallery, for instance, and press the back `Button`, the code in `MainActivity`'s `onBackPressed` is executed, and the current `GalleryFragment` instance is replaced by the instance in the stack, but its `sub_container` is empty (none of `onCreateView` or `onResume` is called).

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, adding the same instance to the stack was not a good idea. Instead, if I add a new instance, it works perfectly, i.e. :

instead of

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).addFragmentToStack(this);
```

use

```
GalleryFragment fragment = new GalleryFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("type", "photos"); // or bundle.putString("type", "videos");
                                    // in order to know what to load once in there
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
((MainActivity)getActivity()).addFragmentToStack(fragment);
```

Comment: This approach is problematic. Never instantiate Fragments with the constructor and don't keep references to it. The system can destroy your fragment at any time, this is why you should always use the FragmentManager method `getFragmentByTag`.

Comment: @DrJerkberg: "Never instantiate Fragments with the constructor". Why?